# Different coloured characters in char array output on C++

Tags: c++, colors, char

I've trouble with changing chars to different color. I want to change 1st letter (uppercase of text) to red color like a Yandex. I've tryed different ways to do this, but no result. System("Color 4") changes full text to red, but I want to change only 1st letter to red. Please help me. Thank you.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>  
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main()
{

    string temp = "the DEVIL hides in the DETAILS";
    int space = 0;


    int length = temp.length();
    char *collect = new char[length+1];

    // Convert string to char loop
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        collect[i] = temp[i];   
    }

    //Changing char to lower or upper case
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        if (space == 1)
        {
            collect[i] = tolower(collect[i]);
        }
        if (space == 0)
        {
            collect[i] = toupper(collect[i]);
            space = 1;

        }
        if (collect[i] == ' ')
        {
            space = 0;
        }

    }
    cout <<  collect<<endl; 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use the ANSI escape codes better for that kind of thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors  you would do something like cout >> escape code red >> letter >> escape code normal colour >> rest of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ standard doesn't support standardized way how to write colored text. The easiest way how to add colors to console output is the usage of ANSI escape sequences. All you have to do is the addition of some special characters and color numbers around your text.

Here's the function that writes a colorized text to console.

```
void ColorPrint(const char* text, int fg_color, int bg_color)
{
    static const char begin_sequence[]{0x1B,'[','\0'};
    static const char reset[]{0x1B,'[','0','m','\0'};

    cout << begin_sequence << fg_color << ';' << bg_color << 'm' << text << reset;
}
```

The following code demonstrates how to use this function. It writes 'some text' with light red foreground color and light green background color.

```
ColorPrint("some text",91,102);
```

On the Linux platforms ANSI escape sequences should work fine. But Windows supports ANSI escape sequences only since Windows 10 TH2 (on previous versions you can use console API functions like `SetConsoleTextAttribute`). And you have to enable ANSI escape sequence support by calling API function `SetConsoleMode` that should be called at the beginning of your program. Here is the example.

```
HANDLE ConsoleOutputHandle=CreateFileA("CONOUT$",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
DWORD Mode=0;

GetConsoleMode(ConsoleOutputHandle,&Mode);

Mode|=ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;

SetConsoleMode(ConsoleOutputHandle,Mode);

CloseHandle(ConsoleOutputHandle);


// Now you should see this text in red/green colors.
ColorPrint("some text",91,102);
```

The following table contains all possible colors.
[ANSI escape sequence color table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3/4_bit).

Depending on console type you are writing to, it can support other effects like text blinking or text underlining. Windows 10 console supports only text underlining. Other effects are still unsupported.